# What are "complementary pair-wise comparable functions"?

Tags: functions

I got this term while studying periodic functions; my book writes:

> If $f_1(x)$ & $f_2(x)$ are periodic functions with periods $T_1$ & $T_2$ respectively, then we have $h(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ has period, as $\dfrac{1}{2} \text{L.C.M. of }\; \{T_1 ,T_2\}$, if $f_1(x)$ & $f_2(x)$ are **complementary pair-wise comparable** functions.

Don't know how the author deduced the rule. But my main question is what do this "**complementary, pair-wise, comparable** function" mean?  I've googled this but it was in vain.

Comment: Thanks. Arihant rocks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it means if you put $(π/2-x)$ in place of $x$ in one of the functions and get the second function, then they are called complementary. Like $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$.

Answer (score -3):

Consider a set of functions $F$.

The set is pairwise comparable if, for any two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ within the set $F$, we know that either:

$f(x) \ge g(x)$ for any value of $x$, or 
$f(x) \le g(x)$ for any value of $x$.

Comment: and what does it mean when you put "complementary" in there?

Comment: This interpretation doesn't seem to make much sense in the context of the question.